# How to replace button in another view with javascript? Remote: true for link_to of an action in has_many trrough assosiation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Sorry for the long title. I don't know how I got stuck this much.

I wanted to have a button (actually a link_to styled as a button) for FOLLOW / UNFOLLOW on remote. That's a Follow model where records are stored for Corporation and User (a User can follow a Corporation). The follow/unfollow links are on the Corporation show page.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if Follow.where(corporation_id: @corporation.id, user_id: current_user.id).first.nil? %>
    <%= link_to 'FOLLOW', {:controller => "follows", :action => "create", :user_id => current_user.id, :corporation_id => @corporation.id}, remote: true, :method => "post", class: "btns follow", id: "follow1" %>
  <% elsif %>
   <%= link_to 'UNFOLLOW', {:controller => "follows", :action => "destroy", :corporation_id => @corporation.id, :user_id => current_user.id }, remote: true, :method => "delete", class: "btns unfollow", id: "unfollow" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

These are the controller actions:

```
def create
  @corporation_id = params[:corporation_id]
  @follow = Follow.new(follow_params)
  @follow.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :file => "/corporations/create.js.erb" }
  end
end

def destroy
  @corporation_id = params[:corporation_id]
  attending.destroy
  #attending is a method where the follow is defined. This is ok.
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :file => "/corporations/destroy.js.erb" }
  end
end
```

I'm rendering create.js.erb in corporations, since the change has to happen there. If I leave it as format.js, it'll search in the follows folder which is empty.

The create.js.erb look like this:

```
$("#unfollow").click(function(){
  $("unfollow").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "corporations/profile/follow", :locals => {corporation_id: @corporation_id}) %>");
});
```

Btw, I tried .html instead of replaceWith, but it's not that.

The destroy.js.erb is similar. And the _unfollow.html.erb partial is like this:

```
<% if !@corporation.nil? %>
  <%= link_to 'UNFOLLOW', {:controller => "follows", :action => "destroy", :corporation_id => @corporation.id, :user_id => current_user.id }, :method => "delete", class: "btns unfollow", remote: true, id: "unfollow" %>
<% else %>
  <%= Rails.logger.info("First here") %>
  <%= Rails.logger.info(corporation_id) %>
  <%= link_to 'UNFOLLOW', {:controller => "follows", :action => "destroy", :corporation_id => corporation_id.to_i, :user_id => current_user.id }, :method => "delete", class: "btns unfollow", remote: true, id: "unfollow" %>
  <%= Rails.logger.info("Now here...") %>
<% end %>
```

Without the first condition it just fires up an error the corporation_id (it's same with locales[:corporation_id]) is not defined and similar.

I have no idea what to try now... All the tutorials on the net are quite simple but the remote action is just one action in the controller where it needs to change, this has to go to another controller then back, then again to Follow... I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: You should make partial of follow and unfollow.. and render it.. instead of link_to..  and in create.js.erb just replace tha form again

Comment: With a few more changes I made it work. Yes, it has to be rendered in the view. Thanks.

Comment: wc.. my pleasure :)